# MongoDB changestreams processing using Apache Spark

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-spark, changestream

**Is it possible to process MongoDB changestreams using Apache Spark ?**

I searched and found there are connectors for reading and writing to mongoDB, but unfortunately I could not find any mention about changestreams.

In my use case, I have to process changestreams from multiple documents simultaneously, please suggest if I could use Apache Spark or something else for it.

Comment: How many documents would you have at max .? Spark is for in-memory parallel computation for large amount of data..And what will be size of the changestreams?

Comment: I believe there will be atleast 100 millions documents stored in the db (which will grow over time) and at a time we may have to process changestreams from 1 million documents.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the use case ? How are you planning to utilise `changestreams` with Spark ? You can read documents from MongoDB into Spark then process them in parallel.